# twitter4j - access tweet information from Streaming API

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

My goal is to collect all tweets containing the words "France" and "Germany" and to also collect associated metadata (e.g., the geo coordinates attached to the tweet). I know that this metadata is available, but I can't figure out how to access it with the Java library I'm using : "twitter4j".

Ok, so what I have so far is taken from code samples on the twitter4j site. It prints out all tweets containing my chosen keywords, as they are provided in real-time by Twitter's Streaming API. I call the filter method on my TwitterStream object, and this provides the stream. But I need more control. Namely, I would like to be able to:

1) write the tweets to a file;
2) only print out the first 1000 tweets;
3) access other metadata attached to the tweet (the filter method just prints out the username and the tweet itself).

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import twitter4j.FilterQuery;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.StatusDeletionNotice;
import twitter4j.StatusListener;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterStream;
import twitter4j.TwitterStreamFactory;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class Stream {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {

    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
    cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("bbb");
    cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("bbb");
    cb.setOAuthAccessToken("bbb");
    cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("bbb");

    TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
    StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {

        public void onStatus(Status status) {
            System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
        }

        public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {
            System.out.println("Got a status deletion notice id:" + statusDeletionNotice.getStatusId());
        }

        public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {
            System.out.println("Got track limitation notice:" + numberOfLimitedStatuses);
        }

        public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {
            System.out.println("Got scrub_geo event userId:" + userId + " upToStatusId:" + upToStatusId);
        }

        public void onException(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    };

    FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();
    String keywords[] = {"France", "Germany"};

    fq.track(keywords);

    twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    twitterStream.filter(fq);      
}
}
```

Comment: Need a help. I'm getting this following error.   'The type new StatusListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method StatusListener.onStallWarning(StallWarning)'

Comment: Which version of Twitter4J are you using? The TwitterStream class doesn't seem to be included in mine. I'm using 3.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at this with fresh eyes I realised the solution (which was pretty obvious). Editing the following part of the code:

```
public void onStatus(Status status) {
        System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
    }
```

allows me to access other metadata. For example, if I want to access the tweet's date, I simply need to add the following:

```
System.out.println(status.getCreatedAt());
```

Answer (score 0):

The Error 401 comes when the API is trying to access some information which is unable to fetch at present. So you need to check the permission which are allowed on twitter. Change it to READ, WRITE and ... for full API access. Or there might be problem as you might be using the proxy server. Hence mention the proxy details using the following commands.

```
 System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "10.3.100.211");
        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "8080");
```

Answer (score 0):

To write tweets on file:

```
FileWriter file = new FileWriter(....);

public void onStatus(Status status) {
    System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText() + " -> "+ status.getCreatedAt());
    try {
        file.write(status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText() + " -> "+ status.getCreatedAt() +"\n");
        file.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```